# Why AJAX is not working in my PHP application?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP application, In this application I am trying to using AJAX.

Below code is for View page. From this page I am trying to go to the controller URL but I am not getting it back after echo the value. Could you please help anyone!

```
   <?php require APPROOT.'/views/inc/header.php'; ?>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <div id="container" class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3"> 
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Search Our Database</h2>
      <input class='form-control' type="text" name='search' id='search' placeholder='Search our inventory'>

      <br>
      <br>
      <h2 class="bg-success" id="result">  rumman  
      </h2>
    </div>  


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').keyup(function(){

            var search = $('#search').val();
       // alert(search);    

            $.ajax({                             
                 url:'Subjects/add',
                 data:{search:search},
                 type: 'POST',
                 success:function(data){        
                    if(!data.error) {  
                    $('#result').html(data); 
                 }  
            }  

        });  
    });
});

</script> 

<?php require APPROOT.'/views/inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

Below is my Controller method inside Subjects controller

```
public function add(){ 

    if(isset($_POST['search'])) { 
            $search = $_POST['search'];
            echo $search; 
    } 

    $this->view('Subjects/add');

 }
```

Comment: And where do you call the `add()` function?

Comment: Hard to go off code provided. Is the `view()` function public / private / protected or even exist in the same class?

Comment: @JayBlanchard , I am calling the add() from AJAX url. [add is a function in the controller]

Comment: can you verify it is actually going into your controller/action? Check your browser console to see where the destination URL .

Comment: @waterloomatt, Subjects/add  is my controller/action, but it's not working. When I am doing this wihout mvc it's working fine. But in case of MVC it's not woking.

Comment: So this is a routing issue? We need more info then pls. Have you crafted your own MVC router or are you using an existing component? What is the URL being called? etc.

Comment: My advice is to try hard-coding everything first and get the basics going first. Change your controller/action to expect a `GET` request and then manually try to hit it using your browser's address bar. Work backwards from there by using AJAX with a `GET` request. Once you have that change it to a `POST` request and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').keyup(function(){

      var search = $('#search').val();   

      $.ajax({                             
        url:'subjects/add',
        data:{search:search},
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(data){        
          if(!data.error) {  
            $('#result').html(data); 
          }  
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```